Side-by-side configuration is incorrect while starting an application
I have a really complicated issue about running a Windows app, and after digging more into the issue I found more issues related to the main one.

So, the first problem is when trying to open "MSI afterburner" program after a clean and successful installation process, I got this error (image below):

"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail."



After I digging more deep into this problem I found this error details in the "Event-viwer" programme log (image below):

"Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI Afterburner\MSIAfterburner.exe". Dependent Assembly
Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."



Then after some searches I found that might be related to the particular "Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable", so I tried to reinstall it.

The x64 version of it installed fine, but not the x86 version of it. the error says (image below):

"Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32". Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070091."

This is only happened for the x86 version during the installation process, the x64 version installed fine.


So now it seems that the whole problem is about the "Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable" the x86 version that the MSI afterburner needs to run.

I've tried every possible solution out there (In-place upgrade, sfc/scannow, DISM commands, .Net framework repair-tool, ext...) and nothing worked (and I hate doing clean install every time I have problems like this.)

And for more diagnostics info, i have another problem that might be related to this issue (my doubts is more than 90%), is that the SFC /scannow keeps finding error and fixes them successfully (like a stuck condition), I’ve posted this issue in the Microsoft community and I didn't any really useful response (and this is the link of it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sfc-keeps-finding-errors-and-fixes-them/c597e753-226c-411b-83bd-7c39a6897428).



How exactly did you determine which version of the VC++ Redistributable MSI Afterburner is required? SFC and DISM do not correct corrupt or invalid installs of non-system files like VC++ Redistributable

Can you [edit] your question to include a screenshot showing that your systems Windows Installer service is running?

I did determine which version is which, by making some searches about the error code that i've got in both 'starting MSI afterburner' and 'installing the VC++ Redistributable', and depend on ChatGPT response too. it seems that that error code referring to that particular Redistributable

I would stop asking ChatGPT for answers to question it cannot answer and focus on the humans requesting information to actually answer you question

you can't imagine how much time I've spent in this issue and how many solutions I've tried. and nothing even was close to solving it. so the ChatGPT was just a final desperate move.

I've tried every possible solution out there, specially that there are multiple issues instead of one (Side-by-side Issue + VC++ 2008 x86 won't install).
After a week looking into these issues, i found the solution, actually it has been posted as a solution to my ms community issue post. Is using the VC++ Repair Tool from this link particularly: Releases · abbodi1406/vcredist
And this tool has forced the VC++ (including the VC++ 2008 x86 that my issue related with) to install. i don't know how, to be honest because i've tried every possible way trying to install the VC++ 2008 x86 and nothing worked.
Any way, this is the only solution worked for me.
(Notice: the SFC problem i've mentioned still exist any way, which means it doesn't related with those issue above)

For most apps that i've installed, if they need the C++ redistributable, then the installation app will install that along with the rest. That is a standard and I've never had a problem like yours. In fact, I'm really surprised if MSIAfterburner installation doesn't have this. Did you try uninstall/reinstall of Afterburner? Sorry if that is too obvious.  Even more obvious is to reboot Windows.
B/C of each program installing is own redistributal, Something that annoys me is that I see multiple installations of the redistributable in my Control Panel -> Programs list. But I assume that even though these have the same content, they are stored in different places on disk. If this is true, then Afterburner might be having trouble to find the redistributal. You might try copying the redistributable (or redistrubutal (^_^) ) to the directory where Afterburner keeps it executables and/or dll's (shared libraries).
The 2008 redistributal version is the most common, but I vaguely remember there might be a more recent one, but it depends on what the app was compiled with. Can you check that 2008 is the right one for your app? Also, do you really need the 32-bit version? Some apps are still 32-bit, but most apps are compiled 64-bit these days.
When you updated Windows, the new version may have some differences with the old one, such as a different set of updates.
Looking on the internet with your error is the right approach. But you'll likely get better info on (XXX)GPT chatbots if they are up to date. I use them instead of Gogogle when appropriate.
Did you contact the manufacturer? If they obfuscate their phone number then usually googling "NameOfBusiness customer support phone number" then you'll find it. Or use a slower method like email. IMO, the chatbots on those sites are useless.
These are all obvious stuff. For me, they almost always solve my problems. And your own problem is "suspicious" to me. There's no way a windows program would require you to install the redistributal by hand. After all, this isn't Linux!   ꉂ(≧▽≦)
Actually, I love Linux.

MSI Afterburner doesn’t really have an installer. It’s a very simple application. So what’s the solution to the authors problem? How exactly do they install the 32-bit VC+ 2008 Redistributable? Your answer seems more of generic advice and a ton of commentary.

Yes, I'm often wordy. Each paragraph is supposed to be a hint toward finding a trail to the solution. Knowing where to start looking is also helpful, if you haven't thought of one of them already.
But I did add a bit that says what you can do if your program can't find the redistributable since the dll libraries are always in the path of a program.

I don’t see your specific recommendation to the author on how to install 32-bit VC++ Redistributable. I see a lot of commentary, including recommendations to use ChatGPT, which is odd given I know for a fact ChatGPT recommendation isn’t worth the effort to such a specific error. Only a human can solve the authors problem.

I guess another point is that if MSIAfterburner is distributed as a simple executable with no dll's or supporting files, then it definitely should NOT need the shared redistributal to be installed separately.  If all they give is an executable, then it will be hard linked (icompiled into) in their executable. They can't guarantee the redistributable is already on the user's machine, so they would be idiots (sorry, I mean, not very knowledgeable) if they failed to include it.
My point is that if no simple executable would be given out that depends on assumptions of dll's.

I wrote, "If this is true, then Afterburner might be having trouble to find the redistributal. You might try copying the redistributable (or redistrubutal (^_^) ) to the directory where Afterburner keeps it executables and/or dll's (shared libraries)."

It’s having difficulty because it’s not installed or corrupt. Copying individual files won’t work That will be a waste of the authors time. They will go into an endless list of requests for different files. Your lack of knowledge with Windows is apparent. As currently written even an expert in Windows cannot answer this question.

It seems that you didn't get my problem well.
I told you that the MSI afterburner error while open it, it is the same as error while installing "Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable" exactly the x86 version.
It's not making me installing the redistributable manually as you said, because the installation went normal without any issue.
Then i tried to install it manually just for being sure that the problem related to that, but it won't be installed.
And this type of problem is rare. Because the only solve for this is the clean install (i had the exact issue before)

@YahiaB. - This problem is easy to solve, but it is difficult to diagnose remotely without access to all the information. If you provide the information users are asking for I can almost guarantee, this problem can be solved, without a in-place install of Windows.

@Ramhound - i think i've provided every possible information about the issue in the post. what you need more. and what infos the users asking for ?

@YahiaB. - I asked for something very specific.

Guess what :) . i've tried installing the "Beta" version of MSI afterburner, and it just worked fine.   and i noticed that there is an installation process for ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI Afterburner\Redist\VCRedistWebSetup.exe" /I /Q 2022" that takes too long time and uses the internet connection. i noticed too that in the normal version of MSI afterburner this process doesnt executed by the installation media. i think the problem start to be more clear now.
